# How to include libuv with CMake

Tags: c++, c, cmake, libuv

I want to include libuv to my project

I tried use find_package but cmake can not find libuv-config.cmake

should I copy the source code to project, or keep trying to use find_package with other ways?

Comment: pkgconfig? https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/CMakeLists.txt https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html

Comment: I would suggest using vcpkg for managing libs, It almost works out of the box.